# How to count unique rows in a column based on multiple conditions in python

Tags: python, pandas, loops, unique

I have a data frame that looks like that : (the treatment has multiple possibily of character variable, I just simplified for the question)

```
ID              Position            Treatment
--20AxECvv-         0           A
--20AxECvv-         -1          A
--20AxECvv-         -2          A
--h9INKewQf-        0           A
--h9INKewQf-        -1          B
zZU7a@8jN           0           B
QUeSNEXmdB          0           C
QUeSNEXmdB          -1          C
qu72Ql@h79          0           C
```

I just want to keep the ID with exclusif treatment, in other word keep ID who was treated by only one treatment even if it was several times. After, I want to sum the number of ID for each treatment. The result would be :

```
ID              Position            Treatment
--20AxECvv-         0           A
--20AxECvv-         -1          A
--20AxECvv-         -2          A
zZU7a@8jN           0           B
QUeSNEXmdB          0           C
QUeSNEXmdB          -1          C   
qu72Ql@h79          0           C
```

And the sum :

```
A : 1 
B : 1
C : 2
```

I have any ida how to resolve this, maybe with a loop within a loop but I am a beginner with Python/panda Thanks

Comment: If multiple treatment under one ID , which one you want to keep?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can groupby ID and filter the rows based on the condition number of unique rows == 1

```
df1 = df.loc[df.groupby('ID').Treatment.filter(lambda x: x.nunique()==1).index]
```

Or as @Igor Raush suggested,

```
df1 = df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda g: g.Treatment.nunique() == 1)    

    ID          Position    Treatment
0   --20AxECvv-     0           A
1   --20AxECvv-     -1          A
2   --20AxECvv-     -2          A
5   zZU7a@8jN       0           B
6   QUeSNEXmdB      0           C
7   QUeSNEXmdB      -1          C
8   qu72Ql@h79      0           C
```

And to get the unique count

```
df1.groupby('Treatment').ID.nunique()

Treatment
A        1
B        1
C        2
```

Comment: Or skip the indexing: `df.groupby('ID').filter(lambda g: g.Treatment.nunique() == 1)`

Comment: @IgorRaush, yes that's more clean. Thank you:)

Comment: Thanks a lot Vaishali and IgorRaush

Comment: And know how I can do to have only the subset with all the first position (ie : the minimum position for each id). Sometimes the first position could be -2 or -65.

I suppose I have to insert a function minimum, but I don't know how to manage it.

Comment: @Anna, Can you pl elaborate? What would be the expected output?

Comment: @Anna, I think you're looking for `df.loc[df.groupby('ID').Position.idxmin()]`